# javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: player not found - PrimeFaces showcase

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use PlayerConverter from PrimeFaces showcase project.
I'm having the following error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: player not found.
```

I've already tried everything from this topic: [javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: player not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035271/javax-faces-facesexception-expression-error-named-object-player-not-found)

Namely:

1.

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>player</converter-id>
    <converter-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.PlayerConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

2.

```
@FacesConverter("player")
```

I've tried to debug ApplicationImpl as found that the "player" key cannot be found in map of converters.

Here is the map:
[image]

I'm using JSF 2.1.20.

Why is the converter not working?