# javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: myConverter not found

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I believe I'm wiring all things correctly, but the converter still won't be recognized in my `xhtml` where I have this following code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... value="#{myBean.myObject}" converter="myConverter">
  ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

where `myConverter` is the converter I'm using to perform the `Object - String` and `String - Object` conversions on `myObject` object (an instance of the type `MyType` below).

Here's the relevant portion of the `myConverter` code:

```
@FacesConverter (value="myConverter", forClass = MyType.class)
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
  ...
}
```

Despite the above configuration, I get the error:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: myConverter not
>   found

I referred to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13035271/934307) (which was missing the above configuration) which suggests an alternative by modifying the `faces-config.xml`, but I think the above config should work well too?  Anyway, I tried the xml approach too - here's the relevant portion of the config:

```
<faces-config ...>
    <converter>
      <converter-id>myConverter</converter-id>
      <converter-class>myPackage.MyConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
</faces-config>
```

Is anything really wrong with the config at all? I see the example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml) doing the exact same thing!

EDIT:
Ok, the stacktrace revealed a bit more useful info:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: myConverter                  not found.
```

I see extraneous spacing after the converter name (the converter id); I tried to modify its value to remove the spaces at the end during remote debugging and it finds my converter (I hit an NPE afterward though, but I guess I can take it up)! Anything obvious on why those spaces are appended to the end of my converter name (or id that is)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find what caused the extra spaces to be inserted at the end of my converter id.

Here's the exact code I had before:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ... converter="myConverter"
  filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" editable="false">
```

which I changed to:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...
  converter="myConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" editable="false">
```

Notice the converter attribute in the new line!  I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious about the formatting/rendering rules surrounding the attributes, but this behavior seems awkward to say the least!

Comment: I honestly doubt this was the cause. It might be that you had an 'old'  file deployed and by changing this, you triggered a kind of redeploy activating a new file (or actually deploying the converter or something). Did you try changing it back? Does it still fail then?

Comment: This is impossible. It's more likely that your build was dirty or that a IDE-managed hotpublish/hotdeploy failed. When something appears to be absent during runtime even though the code behind is present, always perform a full clean, rebuild, redeploy and restart to exclude a dirty build from being the cause.